# How to do this assignment?(making 1 array, making 2 other arrays using the first array, then displaying them)

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, return, logic

i realized that few other people posted this exact same question but we had different codes so i'm just asking a new question...

"Write a program that generates 100 random integers in the range 1 to 100, and stores them in an array. Then, the program should call a class method that extracts the numbers that are even multiples of 4 into an array and returns the array. The program should then call another method that extracts the numbers that are not even multiples of 4 into a separate array and returns the array. Both arrays should then be displayed"

i read my text book which talked about making another array called return but none of the examples are using the technique and neither are other codes.

*****i didn't put the whole code in because it wouldn't fit(i think)

```
public static int eMOF(int[] randomNumbers)
{
    int[] eMOFArray = new int[100];


    int i = 1;

    for (int x : randomNumbers)
    {
        if ( (x / 4) % 2 == 0)
        {       
            eMOFArray[i] = x;
            i = i++;
        }
    }


    return eMOFArray;

}


public static int oMOF(int[] randomNumbers)
{
    int[] oMOFArray = new int[100];

    int i = 1;

    for (int x : randomNumbers)
    {
        if ( x / 4 == 0 & ( x / 4 ) % 2 != 0)
        {   
            oMOFArray[i] = x;
            i = i++;

        }   
    }



    return oMOFArray;

}
```

}

it should display 2 arrays, one with even multiples of four and one with odd multiples of four. Instead, it doesn't compile, and an error message saying

error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

- also can you check my logic please? im strugglingg

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: You may get responses like - don't write in Java, ever - but that's just my *opinion*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Return type should be int[] instead of int as you are returning an array.**

Index of returning array(eMOF or oMOF) i should start from zero as the index of array starts from zero.

Talking about the logic , for both methods initially each element should be checked if it is a multiple of four and then even multiple or odd multiple.

To check whether a even multiple of four : x%4==0 && (x/4)%2==0
x%4 ==0 checks if the element is multiple of 4 and the (x/4)%2==0 checks if the element is even multiple of four.

**'%' gives remainder where as '/' gives quotient.**

```
public static int[] eMOF(int[] randomNumbers)
{
    int[] eMOFArray = new int[100];
    int i = 0;
    for (int x : randomNumbers)
    {
        if ( x % 4 == 0 && ( x / 4 ) % 2 == 0)
        {       
            eMOFArray[i++] = x;
        }
    }
    return eMOFArray;
}


public static int[] oMOF(int[] randomNumbers)
{
    int[] oMOFArray = new int[100];
    int i = 0;
    for (int x : randomNumbers)
    {
        if ( x % 4 == 0 && ( x / 4 ) % 2 != 0)
        {   
            oMOFArray[i++] = x;
        }   
    }
    return oMOFArray;
}
```